# Android SDK Tools rev25.3 以降の Windows + cordova 開発環境でのavd設定ができない

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

＜環境＞
開発環境OS:     Windows7 64bit
android studio: v2.3.2(SDK同梱版)
node:           v4.1.2
npm:            v2.14.4
cordova:        v7.0.1

＜状況＞
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ja/latest/guide/cli/index.html
上記、公式サイトの通りに以下の手順にてhelloworldアプリを作成して
みましたが、avd 関連が上手く設定できていなくて、emulator が起動しません。

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$ cd hello
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova build andoroid
$ cordova emulate android
```

具体的には「cordova emulate android」実施後に以下が表示されます。

```
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 8.616 secs
Built the following apk(s):
        C:/work/hello/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
Error: No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat" sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat" avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver
```

上記ログから avd 設定が抜けていると思い、avdmanager.exe を起動しようとしましたが
インストールした環境にはありませんでした。
調べてみると、Android SDK Tools rev25.3 で単体(exe)のSDK ManagerとAVD Managerはで廃止されているようでした。

＜質問＞
そこで質問なのですが、
(1)Android SDK Tools rev25.3 以降でのwindows+cordovaでのavd設定はどうすればいいのでしょうか？

(2)..sdk\tools\android.bat コマンドから呼び出せる avdmanager.bat がありますが利用方法は何を見ればわかるのでしょうか？
android.bat実行すると以下の内容が表示されるので、「.../android.bat create avd」を実施しましたが 
avdmanager.bat の使い方しか表示されませでした。

```
**************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************

Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

(3)上記の内容から android コマンドは廃止予定のため android studio を利用しろと記載がありますが具体的にどうすれば利用できるのでしょうか？
cordovaコマンド(cordova create)で作成したプロジェクトでも、android studio のプロジェクトとして開いても問題ないのでしょうか？
また android studio で cordova プロジェクトを開いても avd 設定する箇所がみあたりません。

以上、宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

わかる範囲でのみ回答します。
(3)について、エミュレータを確認するにはAndroid Studio上でShiftを2回押してAVD Managerを選択するとavdmanager.exe に近い画面を表示することが可能です。

SDK同梱版なので、問題ないかもしれませんが、念のため、SDK等がインストールされている確認してください。
Android studio上で File → Settings → Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK のPlatformsを参照し、Show package detailにチェックを入れて想定するシステムイメージがインストールされているか確認してください。
ご提示いただいたインストールマニュアルを参照するとAPI 22となっていましたので、該当SDKがインストールされているのかご確認ください。
そのほか、ツール等もインストールするように指示されていますので、SDK Toolsタブから選択してください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。  

お教えいただいた方法(shiftx2)で試しましたが、cordova create コマンドで作成したプロジェクトでは、少なくとも avd manager は候補に挙がってこず起動することができませんでした。(Ctrl+Shift+Aで表示されるactionリストの avd manager はグレーアウトされていました)   
  
そこで、android studio でダミーのandroid アプリのプロジェクトを作成しshiftx2 または Ctrl+Shift+A でavd manager を起動し、希望のavd設定を追加したのち、  
$ cordova emulate android  
で起動できることを確認しました。 

また、 
$ cordova emulate --target=<名前> android 
のようにすれば、avd manager で追加したavd 設定を名前指定で切り替えて利用できることも確認できました。 
ありがとうございました